# JNI callback system from Java to a 3rd party C++ lib

Tags: java, callback, java-native-interface

I've done some research, including here in StackOverflow, but I still have some issues to deal and I kind of need your help.

So, I have a Java lib that's used as wrapper to a 3rd party C++ lib. This C++ lib is where all the logic is. So, it has an asynchronous behaviour and there's the need to register callbacks to get notified for its events. I want to be able to register callbacks from Java and to be able to get notified of their respective events in Java.

Currently I have something like this:

1. A Java method to register a callback (this callback is registered in Java) and to call a C++ "native" method that will register a callback in the 3rd party lib (this is done via C++);
2. Another Java method, named something like "fireMyEvent", to be called by my 3rd party's lib callback (from C++).

The problem here is that when my 3rd party's lib callback is fired I don't have access to the JNIEnv, nor to the jobject.

I've seen here at StackOverflow how to access the JNIEnv pointer by caching a JavaVM pointer. Nevertheless, I'm not sure how to access the jobject instance, to be able to call my CallVoidMethod:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(theJObjectThatIWant, methodId, ...)
```

I though about caching the jobject during the call to the C++ method that registers the callback in my 3rd party lib, but I'm not sure if this is acceptable in a scenario where there are more than one "Java wrapper objects" (I'm referring to the object that wraps the C++ functionality through JNI) in an application.

What are your suggestions to overcome this situation?

I hope I've made made my problem clear and I apologize if my research wasn't good enough to find an already existing answer in this forum :(.

Many thanks and regards.

**Edit**:
Caching the "*jobject*" doesn't seem to be working, because I end up having an "Access violation" executing the "*CallVoidMethod*" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cache a Java reference beyond the end of a native call, a global reference is required.

See ["Local and global references" in this JNI reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html#27423).

Comment: It worked, thanks! :) I used something like: "g_jObject = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);" where "obj" is the method's parameter.

Comment: Nevertheless, if I instantiate two "Java wrapper objects" (instances of the class that uses JNI), I can see that in the second object my "cached jobject" has the value from the first one. So, I still have half of the problem to solve, to make the cached JNI variables independent between instances of the "Java wrappers".

Comment: Are the cached jobject's pointing to the two Java wrapper objects? When you say that they have the same value, do you mean that they have the same value as a native pointer?

Comment: Hi! I set the value of g_jObject in my native constructor (called by the Java Wrapper's constructor). So, when I'm debugging the native constructor, when I create the second Java Wrapper, I can see that my g_jObject has the same hexa address as it had when it was set in the creation of the first Java Wrapper instance. So, when I set the value of g_jObject in my 2nd Java Wrapper instance, that's the value that'll have from now on, whether I'm in the scope of the 1st Java Wrapper instance, or in the 2nd. But, so far, thanks for your interest! :)

Comment: Does your g_ prefix mean global C variable or global JNI reference?

Comment: Well, it means both. It is a C global variable that stores the value of the "NewGlobalRef".

Comment: I see. You're right, a single global variable can't hold two different values. You need some way to hold and access each global JNI reference separately. How you do that depends partly on the third-party callback API.